# pandas dataframe shift dates

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is indexed by dates. I'd like to shift just the dates, one business day forward (Monday-Friday), without changing the size or anything else. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can shift with 'B' (I think this [requires numpy >= 1.7](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days-experimental)):

```
In [11]: rng = pd.to_datetime(['21-11-2013', '22-11-2013'])

In [12]: rng.shift(1, freq='B')  # 1 business day
Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-11-22 00:00:00, 2013-11-25 00:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

On the [Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) (same on a [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)):

```
In [21]: s = pd.Series([1, 2], index=rng)

In [22]: s
Out[22]: 
2013-11-21    1
2013-11-22    2
dtype: int64

In [23]: s.shift(1, freq='B')
Out[23]: 
2013-11-22    1
2013-11-25    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I know I didn't ask this in my original question, but how would you shift just 1 column along with the dates (leaving all other columns as is)?

Comment: I think you'll want to shift the column/series, and then set that to a column in the DataFrame. That is, `df[col] = df[col].shift(1, freq='B')`.